# How to link Azure Active Directory "Service Principal" with AKS Kubernetes "Service Account"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-aks

Currently I am trying to deploy applications inside an AKS kubernetes cluster on Azure.

For the deployment pipeline I would like to use a service account which is managed through azure active directory (e.g. service principal).

I already have created a service principal through the Azure CLI.

What is the right way to make this **service principal** known as a **service account** inside the AKS cluster?

The reason I need a need a **service account** and not a **user account** and  is because I want to use it from my devops pipeline without requiring a login, but still be able to manage it through active directory.

Currently I'm using the default service account to deploy my containers inside a namespace, this works but the account is only known inside the namespace and not centrally managed.

```
# This binding enables a cluster account to deploy on kubernetes
# You can confirm this with
# kubectl --as="${USER}" auth can-i create deployments
# See also: https://github.com/honestbee/drone-kubernetes/issues/8
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: default-deploy
rules:
- apiGroups: ["extensions"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get","list","patch","update", "create"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-default-deploy
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: default-deploy
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
# working, the default account configured with deploy permissions
- name: default
  kind: ServiceAccount
  namespace: default
# works, if the service principal is configured as a User
- name: "111111-0000-1111-0000-********"
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
# this does not work, the service principal is configured as a Service Account
- name: "111111-0000-1111-0000-********"
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ServiceAccount
```

I would expect to be able to configure the service account also through RBAC, however I get the following error:

```
The RoleBinding "role-default-deploy" is invalid: 
subjects[1].apiGroup: Unsupported value: 
"rbac.authorization.k8s.io": supported values: ""
```

Comment: You can take a look at [Integrate AAD with AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aad-integration), but the first o all, you should be the admin user of your tenant.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: For AAD user/group it is possible (manual kubectl access) at the moment (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-rbac)) but for automation you can't use it... Its an open request I guess, see [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/10495), [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/914020-azure-kubernetes-service-aks/suggestions/35146387-support-non-interactive-login-for-aad-integrated-c) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/556)